Ubuntu 22.04 automatically logs out from college Wi-Fi
I am a teacher working in a college. We connect to the college WiFi to access the internet. My problem is as follows.
I successfully managed to log in and run the internet on my laptop with Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS. After some time, it automatically logs out. Then again, I do the same thing. After two successful logins and running the internet, the third time I tried to log in, it did not allow me to do so. I am not able to remove this problem on my laptop. The internet on my laptop works fine when I connect to my mobile hotspot. I also can connect with the same WiFi with the Windows operating system or my mobile phone and the internet works fine.
I cannot find Network Options in my Network tab of the Settings app, so I did the following setting. Settings -> WiFi -> From the set of different WiFi I click the setting of the WiFi which I am using -> n add 1.1.1.1 in the DNS. After that, I click Apply. Just before DNS there is an automatic button that is on. It adds an extra DNS 1.1.1.1 in my original DNS list. I am not finding any other change.

I can connect with the same WiFi with the Windows operating system or my mobile phone and the Internet works fine.

I cannot find Network Options in my Network tab of the Settings app. So I did the following setting. Settings->WiFi->From the set of different WiFi I click the setting of the WiFi which I am using->Ipv4 tab I do the following. Select Ipv4 method Automatic(DHCP) and then add 1.1.1.1 in the DNS. After that, I click Apply. Just before DNS there is an automatic button that is on. It adds an extra DNS 1.1.1.1 in my original DNS list. I am not finding any other change.

Any help in this my problem still persists.
